# itunesconnect Upload more than 5 screen images

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

As per my knowledge We can upload 5 Screenshot per screen size.

Apple Document says here: [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW2)

> One screenshot is required. Up to four additional screenshots can be uploaded

It means maximum five screenshot we can upload.

But I found [an app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/map-of-the-dead/id613176595?mt=8) with 6 screenshot. I am wondering how it can happen?

Dose in past apple allows more image to upload or there is any special rule which can allow developers to do so.

Comment: why don't you create two images in one,so that you can put 10 images .

Comment: Have u seen that app?

Comment: Perhaps one was a video?

Comment: @Chris No, I check in safari and in device App store also all 6 are images.

Comment: Can you share the link of that app ?

Comment: @MidhunMP  I have already shared it click on "an app".